# Problem with opening mega dropdown navigation menu only in Safari browsers

Tags: drop-down-menu, safari, navigation, focus, megamenu

I have an explicit problem with displaying my mega dropdown menu only in Safari browsers. This is the case for the most Apple devices. Only one test on the most modern Iphone worked a little well but still with bugs. The other devices didnt't open the dropdown on click, neither on big screen nor on small screen (I wrote it responsive). I already checked, if the installed Safari on the different devices is actuallized. This doesn't fix the problem. Also the -webkit properties doesn't fix it.

I used this multi-level dropdown menu by Victoria Kronsell: 
https://medium.com/swlh/building-a-css-only-responsive-multi-level-mega-menu-ee0a3781cc3f

Answer (score 0):

Just after writing my question I have found a solution and still posted the question, just in case some other people had the same problem. If not necessary I will just delete the question.

The code was provided by Victoria Kronsell, see her example on CodePen: 
https://medium.com/swlh/building-a-css-only-responsive-multi-level-mega-menu-ee0a3781cc3f

She already stated that there will be problems with Safari, because "Safari, for example, does not apply a :focus state on click".

The solution is working with polyfill. I have edited my code with the following scripts and now the menu opens in safari browsers:

https://gist.github.com/NickGard/43328a4e223698e6a63cbff410e35342#file-safari-focus-polyfill-js

https://github.com/matteobad/focus-within-polyfill/blob/master/src/focus-within.js

https://github.com/WICG/focus-visible/blob/main/src/focus-visible.js